# How to remove character literals from string?

Tags: c#

How can i remove character literals from string?

Current text looks like this:

```
<span class=\"comment\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t2 hours ago&nbsp;\r\n\t\t\t\t<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>
```

But i want it like this:

```
<span class="comment">2 hours ago&nbsp;</span></div>
```

I have tried

```
string replacement = Regex.Replace(response, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
```

but its not working.

Comment: Backslash has no special meaning in HTML: `\t` is two characters. In C# it is the escape sequence for a tab. If that really your HTML then you need to match a backslash followed by r/n/t not a control character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape

> \

try this:

```
Regex.Replace(response, @"\\t|\\n|\\r", "")
```

Comment: Not it in a litteral (`@` prefixed) string: baskslash has no special meaning.

Comment: @Richard As it's Regex, the double backslashes are needed.  With a single backslash the Regex will be looking for actual tabs and new lines, not the text literals.

Answer (score -1):

What about this one to remove the slash with quote?

```
Regex.Replace(values[1].Trim(), @"\""", "")
```